# How to handle deletion of files within a database transaction?

Tags: .net, database

I wish to delete a document which resides in a database. Document has some attachments which are located in a file system. Business logic first deletes everything in a database then removes the files. However, this procedure is often a part of a larger transaction and when rollback happens the document is restored but without the attachments. How to solve this?

I see two solutions for this:

1. Delete files at the very end of transaction. In our framework this is not plausible solution I think.
2. Store files in a database. This would work but it demands rewriting and retesting a whole lot.

Perhaps I'm missing some easier solution. Can you share your thoughts on this subject? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning with Vista, NTFS offers true transactions with support for commit and rollback. Overview on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) and details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx).

Comment: +1, I had totally missed that. Do you have any information or experience on how to use that in a C#/.NET program?

Comment: No, I have not used Transactional NTFS yet.

Comment: From Helge's link: "you can now enlist transacted file operations within the same transaction as SQL operations" ....awesome!

Comment: I'll try this approach. I've already found a site which provides an example implementation [here](http://improve.dk/archive/2009/02/15/utilizing-transactional-ntfs-through-dotnet.aspx)
Edit: Doesn't work for Windows 2003 server. Just my luck I suppose. :(

Comment: You might also want to look at the free AlphaFS (I have not used it, but looks promising): http://alphafs.codeplex.com/

Comment: I keep forgetting about the transactional NTFS :)

Comment: "You shouldn’t use TxF if you have a system that will have long-running transactions. A long-running transaction is any transaction that has been alive longer than many other transactions within the same log. This could mean a few seconds if there are thousands of transactions happening and lasting for very brief periods of time. On the other hand, a day or two might not be a long time if there are very few transactions happening in the system."

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are short of harddrive space, I would not delete anything - either on the filesystem or in the database; I'd simply create a status flag against the database record with "deleted" as the new status.

This is on the assumption that the only route to the objects on the filesystem is through the application - if you have humans browsing the filestore, this may not work.

I much prefer managing object deletion through status flags - it prevents the kind of scenario you describe where you've got distributed transactions, but it also allows you to track the history of your business domain, which helps track down bugs.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>A normal file system is not a transactional resource. Store the files in the database to get transactional support.</strike> Please read Helge Klein's answer. This feature has obviously finally been added to Windows.

If you are using SQL2008 there is a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) featured which I think can allow you to handle files within the database but still access them as files through a path. Maybe that is an upgrade path which won't require rewrite of the whole application right away.

Comment: My application uses Enterprise Library to connect to any database which has an ADO.NET provider. Storing files in a database is a valid approach but it demands a rewrite of code. A bit expensive at this point since the application is already in production.